# How to custom code block and text output of Rmarkdown in blogdown?

Tags: css, r, rstudio, netlify, blogdown

How to custom code block and text output of Rmarkdown in blogdown?

I use a theme from https://github.com/zzossig/hugo-theme-zdoc.

It works on md file (https://jiwooblog.netlify.app/posts/dataengineering/fc_part4_3/),

but it is hard to distinguish code blocks and output lines... (https://jiwooblog.netlify.app/posts/r/na_imputation/)

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear what you want to achieve. Have a look here => [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Prehaps this will help: [Style code blocks and text output](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/chunk-styling.html)